# How to install many fonts at once on Linux?

Tags: fonts

I just switched over from Windows to Linux Mint. 
However, as I do web design, there are many fonts on my Windows hard disk that I would want to carry over to my Linux installation.
It is possible to install fonts by double-clicking them from within a file manager and then pressing the 'install' button, but this only works for one font at a time.

As I have about five-hundred of them, I would like to install all of them at the same time.

What I've tried to do is copy over all fonts from the Windows Fonts folder `(C:\Windows\Fonts)` to `/usr/share/fonts/opentype/windows_fonts` and `/usr/share/fonts/truetype/windows_fonts`

However, none of the fonts show up correctly. Instead, programs that use those fonts read all glyphs as white boxes (e.g. 'unknown characters')

Is there another way to install them all at once (or to automate installing them)?

Comment: Try to install Microsoft Fonts as first try using `sudo apt-get install ttf-mscorefonts-installer`. You can also try to update font cache using `sudo fc-cache -fv`.

Answer (score 17):

If you need to install a lot of fonts, then copy the files to `~/.fonts` or `/usr/share/fonts` for system-wide installation and issue the command `fc-cache -fv`.

Comment: what about font cache update I've mentioned, it worked for me?

Answer (score 3):

There are many font managers about and most Linux Distro DE's come with one pre-installed. I use KDE and I can simply drag and drop fonts directly onto my font manager. It does the rest.

Just type Font in the search field in your application menu. Not sure if that will work for Linux Mint though.

Also it may be possible that non true type fonts don't display properly in Linux Mint as well as other types. I am guessing here and I could be totally wrong, but some of your fonts simply may not be compatible. Perhaps if you posted what fonts are not showing correctly others may be able to help further. Perhaps only a certain type is not working.

Answer (score 1):

If you need all fonts available on Linux Mint/Debian (which are many: http://fonts.debian.net), you can use:

```
sudo apt-get install ^fonts-*
```

Comment: Good idea, but it didn't work on my Debian 10 (stable). `Note, selecting 'fonts-georgewilliams' for regex '^fonts-*'` (this message repeated for many different fonts, but none were installed, even after reboot). I've got the message "Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable distribution that some required packages have not yet been created or been moved out of Incoming."